# How to get all intersections between two simple polygons in O(n+k)

Tags: computational-geometry, constraints

Basically the formulation of the problem I'd like to solve is very simple. Given 2 simple polygons (without self-intersections) report all intersecting edge pairs in *O(n+k)* time, where n - is a total number of edges, k - number of intersections between two polygons.

It is very important to stay within mentioned time hardness. What does surprise me, that I could hardly find information on this subject. Polygon intersections seems to be so natural and important problem. Anyway at the moment I don't have a clue if it is even possible to do it in *O(n+k)*.

Can please someone help with lower bounds for this problem?

---

Some additional points on my question:

1. Polygon clipping with set operations and intersection reporting (about which my question was) seems to be slightly different problems - Having found intersecting edges you would have to constract a polygon which is a result of clipping/set operation.
2. An approach based on segment intersection algorithm won't work for me. As it is proved that worst case takes O(nlogn+k).
3. I'm not insisting that an algorithm with such hardness exist - it may not. But in this case I would really appreciate if someone could provide a lower bound proof for my problem - tons of papers provide some very interesting algorithm (usually with O(nlogn+k) complexity) but for some reason don't mention the lower bound.

Comment: Have you considered these implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection ?

Comment: Are the polygons convex?

Answer (score 8):

The $\mathcal{O}(n+k)$ algorithms seem to be limited to convex polygons. The fastest algorithms that I have found   [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300499000710)  and  [here](ftp://ftp.geoinfo.tuwien.ac.at/frank/4756_Intersection_Nonconvex_Polygons_Using_Alternate_Hierarchical_Decomposition.pdf) have approximately $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$ algorithms.  According to [this](http://www.tcs.tifr.res.in/~ghosh/lec-coimbatore-jan2011.pdf), the problem of simple polygon intersection is linear time
transformable to line-segment intersection testing, which has an optimal bound of approximately $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n) + k)$ according to [this](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=147511) article.

Comment: If $n$ is the (total) number of edges, it is impossible to get $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$ running time, as in the worst case, you may have $\Theta(n^2)$ number of intersections. What they state in the abstract of the article that I can see (the link to the other one is broken) is that they can obtain $\mathcal{O}((n+I)\times\log_2(n+I))$, where $I$ is the number of intersection points (and $n$ is called $k$ in the abstract).

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, this cannot be done in $O(n+k)$ time, as there can be as many as $4\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor$, i.e., [Θ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)(*nk*) intersection points.

If the two polygons are convex, however, you can find the intersections in $O(n+k)$ time.

See [Computational Geometry in C Second Edition](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Computational-Geometry-in-C-Second-Edition-O%E2%80%99Rourke/0e97152b766ecbe29f0850a419ba3ba725d38463), page 253, or [Shamos (1978)](http://euro.ecom.cmu.edu/people/faculty/mshamos/1978ShamosThesis.pdf), page 116.